# Gifs in form of JLabel are fickering in Jframe

Tags: java, swing, exception, awt, animated-gif

I created a program to display a GIF but when I added it in the form of a `JLabel` it played but it flickered and flashed and was not continuous which looks very bad and I'm seeking for a way to overcome this issue.

```java
try {
    JLabel j = new Label();
    j.setBounds(0, 0, 1280, 768);
    ImageIcon i = new ImageIcon("frac.gif");
    j.setIcon(i);
} catch (NullPointerException e) {

}
```

And then add it to a `JFrame` and as soon as it displays the GIF flashes.

Please look into the matter.

Comment: I think your problem may be caused by the fact that GIFs can be animated. Rather than trying to fix this in Java, I'd recommend trying convert your GIFs into PNGs or JPEGs.

Comment: Can you post a link to the GIF? What platform are you on? What Java version are you using?

Comment: From the code in your question: `JLabel j = new Label();` Is that a mistake?

Comment: First of all, you should *never* enclose your code with something like `try { … } catch (NullPointerException e) {

}`